# Write to file when different in Unix

Tags: bash, file, unix

I have string in variable, and I want to write it string from variable to file, but only if this string and contents of the file are different.

Comment: Why not just write it? Do you need to keep the modification time unchanged? Also, please show your current attempt.

Comment: @LevLevitsky This could be an answer

Comment: @LevLevitsky Generally You are right, but in this case, each time, when i write to this file also i have to dosconnect network interface. So i want write to file when necessary, but thank You for the comment.

Comment: @user1825271 That comment puts this question deep in "We need more information" territory.

Comment: Problem is solved. I would like to thank You all for Your help. All three ideas are great. Thank You once again. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to store the content of the file in a variable and do a check if the variables are same. Something like:

```
[[ "$var" != "$checkvar" ]] && echo "$var" >> file || echo "content same"
```

#### Test:

```
$ var=jaypalsingh        # Create a variable
$ cat file               # Content of the file
jaypalsingh
$ checkvar=$(<file)      # Add the content of the file to variable
$ [[ "$var" != "$checkvar" ]] && echo "$var" >> file || echo "content same"
content same
```

```
$ var=jaypal
$ [[ "$var" != "$checkvar" ]] && echo "$var" >> file || echo "content same"
$ cat file
jaypalsingh
jaypal
```

Now this will get messier and complicated if you file is big with many lines. The variables will need to have explicit new lines in them.

```
$ var=jaypalsingh$'\n'jaypal     # Variable with new line
$ echo "$var"
jaypalsingh
jaypal
$ cat file
jaypalsingh
jaypal
$ checkvar=$(<file)
$ [[ "$var" != "$checkvar" ]] && echo "$var" >> file || echo "content same"
content same
```

Quotes around `[[..]]` are not needed but usage here will protect against meta-characters as suggested in the comments by [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964072/write-to-file-when-different-in-unix-bash-script/23964258#comment36921008_23964258). He also makes another valid point regarding usage of `echo` here. `printf` will be more suited here to generate your variable.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks, have added quotes.

Comment: +1 for being pure bash. However, using `echo` like this means it won't do anything if `var='-n'`

Comment: @thatotherguy Good point again. `:)`. Have added a note regarding this and possibility of using `printf`. Appreciate the great feedback. Thanks for improving the answer.

Comment: This method would give slight inaccuracy with the newline on the last line as `$(<file)` would ignore it on expansion. Using recursive comparison with `readarray` would be better as it doesn't exclude them. Just don't use `-t`.

Comment: Another problem could also happen if an IO failure occurs with `echo "$var" >> file`. It's unlikely but if it happens it could cause `echo "content same"` to be called. On cases like this when possible error could occur on the `true` action line, using `if.. else` statements would be better. Forms like `[[ case ]] && true || false` are accepted shortcut hacks in Bash but this time the form is a dirty one in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following script:

```
string="foo"

# Use diff to check if the file's content and the variable differ
# <(...) is called "process substitution"
diff file <(cat <<< "$string")

# diff returns 0 if both inputs are the same
[ $? -ne 0 ] || cat <<< "$string" > file
```

Comment: This looks for a file named `foo`, and doesn't compare the file contents with the string "foo"

Comment: +1 for being the most correct. You can also use `diff -q` or `cmp` to avoid generating a full patch, and optionally just `&&` on the same line instead of having a separate check on `$?`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! They are all +1 :) ... I'll keep my answer as is in order to let others see how it can be improved by your suggestions. (Although having the diff and the final cat not on one line - combined with || - looks not satisfying anymore after you told this ...)

Answer (score 2):

```
>> echo hello world > file
>> cat file
hello world
>> str="hello world"
>> if [ "$(diff file <(echo $str))" != "" ]; then echo $str >> file; fi
>> cat file
hello world
>> str="hello SO"
>> if [ "$(diff file <(echo $str))" != "" ]; then echo $str >> file; fi
>> cat file
hello world
hello SO
```

If you want to overwrite `file` instead of appending to it, use `echo $str > file`.

Comment: This doesn't work if `str="-n"`, `str="*"` or `str="foo    bar"`

Comment: @that other guy thanks for the hint, do you see a way to salvage my solution to work properly with this special cases?

Comment: Instead of `echo $str`, you can use `printf "%s\n" "$str"`

Comment: @that other guy thank you. Learning something new every day. :)